# How can I prevent wrapping in a WPF FlowDocument in C# code?

Tags: c#, wpf, word-wrap, flowdocument

[Studies have shown](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/05e02dc6-c8e5-42e8-b755-505e66155c3c/) this is the way to prevent wrapping in, say, a Paragraph:

```
<Paragraph>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap">unwrapping text</TextBlock>
</Paragraph>
```

How can I get the behavior in C# code?

```
new Paragraph(new TextBlock()
{
    Text = "unwrapping text",
    TextWrapping = TextWrapping.NoWrap
});
```

Yields `cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' to 'System.Windows.Documents.Inline'` because Paragraph's constructor is expecting an Inline.

I can't seem to find a way to convert a TextBlock to an Inline to make Paragraph happy. If it works in XAML, there should be a converter somewhere, right? How do I find it?

I realize the point of a FlowDocument is for things to wrap and flow and be re-sizable, etc. I'm writing some simple reports, just some `System.Windows.Documents.Table`s of data, and unfortunately the first column that wraps is one which contains dates, so

```
2013-04-24
```

Becomes

```
2013-04-
24
```

I've been using `Run`s so far, and while they have some `TextBlock` properties, they offer no `TextWrapping` or `TextTrimming` affordances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to add the `TextBlock` to the inlines, the constructor won't do it for you.  I think it would be easiest to just write:

```
var p = new Paragraph();
p.Inlines.Add(new TextBlock()
{
    Text = "unwrapping text",
    TextWrapping = TextWrapping.NoWrap
});
```

Comment: note that this won't suite when the data is huge ... TextBlock will slow the UI down