# RichtextBox editing inline

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, paragraph

I have an array of sentences. Every sentence is a new Run object inside Inlines property of richtextbox`s FlowDocument.
Every sentence have a color.

```
        var paragraph = new Paragraph(); 
        foreach (var sentence in Sentences)
        {
            ....
            paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = sentence, Background = new SolidColorBrush(color) });
        }
        tbText.Document.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
```

When I am editing the sentence like this (I changed 'yes' to 'y1111111111111es' )

I expected to get the same Run object with changed text from 'yes' to 'y1111111111111es' but instead I got 3 Run objects with 'y', '1111111111111111111' and 'es'

That`s how I retrieve the textes

```
        foreach (Paragraph paragraph in tbText.Document.Blocks)
        {
            foreach (Run inline in paragraph.Inlines)
            {
                editedTextes.Add(inline.Text);
            }
        }
```

Is there any way to edit the text inside native Run object without populating new Run objects when I change the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems [FlowDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970909(v=vs.100).aspx) dynamically adds runs to encourage wrapping by design.

I see from another [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194569/how-can-i-prevent-wrapping-in-a-wpf-flowdocument-in-c-sharp-code), that if you use a TextBlock instead of runs inside of Paragraphs, you can preserve your text and remove the runs and prevent wrapping.

Try this in your second block:

```
    foreach (Paragraph paragraph in tbText.Document.Blocks)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (Run inline in paragraph.Inlines)
        {
            sb.Append(inline.Text);
        }

        editedTextes.Add(new TextBlock()
        {
           Text = sb.ToString(),
           TextWrapping = TextWrapping.NoWrap
        });

    }
```

Or just add one run after you have built the string if you don't like the TextBlocks:

```
    editedTextes.Add(sb.ToString());
```